# Put data on the scale (and lessen the power of top high numbers)

Tags: python, math

Problem:

Set of data like these:

```
[64, 54, 5, 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001]
```

Goal:

Put them on the scale (0-1) but, not relatively to max numbers because then everything will be too small because top high numbers are quite too big and rare.

I know there are some options like rescaling data, for example, Sklearn has either StandardScaler and MinMax scaler.

If i try min max scaler, i get from the data above this:

```
array([[1.00000000e+00], 1
       [8.43747559e-01], 0.84
       [7.81105955e-02], 0.07
       [1.56096189e-02], 0.015
       [1.54689917e-03], 0.0015
       [1.40627197e-04], 0.00014
       [0.00000000e+00]])
```

Which is the same as putting the respective number to the max number (e.g. 5/64). This is good but as I say, the result is that 90% of the dataset is too small, and I don't want that.

The only thing I found so far is:

```
# 1. Use the data as the power of 2:
    data3 = [pow(2, a) for a in data]

    # output:
    [18446744073709551616, 18014398509481984, 32, 2, 1.0717734625362931, 1.0069555500567189, 1.0006933874625807]
 
# 2. Now either log them with base 10 or double log them with base 10. Note that if I log them only once, the ratio between numbers is the same as above with MinMax scaler on initial data.

    # If I log them once:
    data4 = [log(a, 10) for a in data3]

    #output: 
    [19.265919722494793, 16.255619765854984, 1.5051499783199058, 0.30102999566398114, 0.030102999566398104, 0.0030102999566398443, 0.00030102999566402835]

    # If I log them twice:
    data4 = [log(log(a, 10), 10) for a in data3]

    #output:
    [1.284789746329562, 1.2110035321686436, 0.17757977668169395, -0.5213902276543249, -1.5213902276543247, -2.52139022765432, -3.5213902276542566]

# 3. Now if i Min max scale them:
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    d = scaler.fit_transform(np.reshape(data4, (-1,1)))

    #output:
    array([[1.        ],
           [0.98464764],
           [0.76962786],
           [0.62419635],
           [0.4161309 ],
           [0.20806545],
           [0.        ]])
```

You see the ratios are a bit another now, the third number is 76%, not 7% as on the top. But these are just some random tries.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think you should ask the question on https://mathoverflow.net/ since it is purely a math problem.

Comment: @TDG i did already but no answer